# Can I cook Brussels sprouts in a pan?

Tags: brussels-sprouts

Can I cook Brussels sprouts in a pan, with olive oil or butter?

I bought them in a plastic bag. Should I chop them, or can I just wash them and put them in the pan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but the surface-to-mass ratio means that the outer layers will overcook well before the inside is cooked, so unless you're interested in that texture, your two main options are:

1. Steam them (add some liquid, then put a lid on it)
2. Cut them smaller.  (halve or quarter before you saute)

I tend to halve smaller ones, and quarter larger ones, cutting through the stem each time so they don't fall completely apart while cooking (after trimming a little off the stem if it's showing signs of drying out).  Then saute 'til the outside has browned a little bit, and hit with salt and whatever spices (or bacon ... dice up some bacon and render the fat while you cut up the sprouts, then use the fat for cooking the sprouts)

Answer (score 1):

You can just throw them in like you would asparagus. They will be a bit crispy: ideal!

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways I make brussel sprouts.

One is to simply coat them with a little olive oil, lots of chopped garlic (i love garlic but you can adjust to your taste), some salt and roast in an oven for about a half hour until they get a little crispy.

Second is to saute them in a pan with some garlic olive oil and salt.  Saute for a few minutes then add some chicken stock/drippings just enough to cover them a third of the way.  Cook on med-high heat until all the stock reduces. Then wrap the sprouts in tin foil with a slice or two of lemon and roast for 20-30 min.

You can also add some rosemary, italian seasoning, or pepper to change the flavors slightly.